# Code to Change Live Hyperlinks into Text URLs not working

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I need to Change Live Hyperlinks into Text URLs I have the following Code but after running it the Hyperlinks are still live

I have `Internet and networkpaths with hyperlink` un-checked

thanks

```
Sub RemoveHyperLink()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range, Cell As Range
Dim LC As Long, LR As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Updated_UnMatched")
With ws
  LC = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  LR = .Cells.Find("*", [a1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
  Set Rng = .Range("A2").Resize(LR, LC)
End With

For Each Cell In Rng
  If Cell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
      Cell.Value = Cell.Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address
  End If
Next Cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some types of Hyperlinks overwriting the cell value deletes the hyperlink (eg links to locations in the workbook), for other like yours it does not.  So you need to actively delete the hyperlink.

Also, you can iterate the Hyperlinks collection of a range or Worksheet, much more efficient and convenient than iterating all cells (assuming you want to process all hyperlinks on the sheet)

Here's your code refactored to account for these issues.  This code will work for any type of hyperlink.

Note that some types of hyperlink may hold the text of interest in the `SubAddress` property.  In either case the other property is blank, so concatinating them works for both cases.

```
Sub demo()
    Dim hl As Hyperlink
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim txt As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Updated_UnMatched")

    For Each hl In ws.Hyperlinks
        Set cl = hl.Parent
        txt = hl.Address & hl.SubAddress
        hl.Delete
        cl.Value = txt
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Chris I tryed both solutions and your was the most efective in that it changed the most URLs to text, `thank you`.  Not all Links were chaged here are two examples that were not changed (by either code) `http://www.website.org/default/index.cfm` and the other `https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-1/c2.0.160.160/p160x160/936402_476943495707654_744317796_n.jpg?oh=290bf9f1c50178d302844de6cb8323c5&oe=55258204&__gda__=1428384763_95aeed00d7fafced4ac86d269be63a87` is there something about these links that need special treatment?, thanks again

Comment: Hello Chris, it turns out the links that were still `blue` were not live so the code did change all the HL to text, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hyperlinks are a property of a `Range` or a `sheet`, not of an individual cell.

So how about this

```
//..your original code for getting the Range Rng

//..then use this For Each loop:
Dim HL as Hyperlink
For Each HL In Rng.Hyperlinks
HL.Delete 'This will effectively replace the cells contents with the URL 
Next
```

Comment: An "individual cell" _is_ a range too. Also, this answer breaks writing the URL back to the sheet.  That said, iterating the `Range.Hyperlinks` collection is a better method, better still is the `Worksheet.Hyperlinks` collection

Comment: @chrisneilsen `Worksheet.Hyperlinks` would target things outside of `Rng`, from the question it looks like OP only wants to manipulate things in `Rng`. Also,  calling `HL.Delete` *does* write the URL to the sheet: it replaces the contents of the hyperlinked cell with the text value of the URL.

Comment: If you look at the OP code is getting the used range on the sheet, so worksheet.Hyperlinks is equivalent.  If the OP want to scan a smaller range, then of course use Range.Hyperlinks.  Delete writes the TextToDisplay property to the sheet, which may or may not be the URL

Comment: @chrisneilsen Ah, I see what you mean now about the 'used range' part. For the second part about delete, I didn't know that.

Comment: Thanks for the responce chiliNUT